# FCF is working but I get this warning: Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, eslint

I wrote a http FCF that run two transactions chained. It works, but I do not know why Im getting this warning:

```
119:16  warning  Avoid nesting promises  promise/no-nesting
```

This is the function I wrote:

```
exports.checkeaEstadoFinanciero = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const RestoID = body.id;
  const db = admin.firestore();
  const restoRef = db.collection('Restaurantes').doc(RestoID);
  const facturasRef = db.collection('Facturas').where('restaurantID', '==', RestoID);
  return db.runTransaction(transaction => {
    return transaction.get(restoRef).then((restoDoc) => {
      if (restoDoc) {
        if ((restoDoc.data().cicloFacturacion.termino - Date.now()) < 0) {
          //emite una factura
          restoRef.set({ httpPropTest: 'worked fine' }, { merge: true });
        }
      }
      return null;
    })
    .then(() => {
      return db.runTransaction(tran => {
        return tran.get(facturasRef).then(facturasDoc => {
          const holder = [];
          facturasDoc.forEach(doc => {
            holder.push(doc.data());
          })
          console.log('facturas documents', holder);
          return null;
        })
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('error: ', err));
  })
})
```

I read this thread from other user:

[Google Cloud Functions - warning Avoid nesting promises promise/no-nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844854/google-cloud-functions-warning-avoid-nesting-promises-promise-no-nesting)

Im doing what the most accepted answer suggest but I still having this warning.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that ESlint is looking at your second transaction:

```
.then(() => {
  return db.runTransaction(tran => {
    return tran.get(facturasRef).then(facturasDoc => {
      const holder = [];
      ...
    })
  })
})
```

And complaining about the call to `then()` inside another `then()` callback.  It doesn't understand that the embedded then() for the transaction is not really related to the first.

You could try to hide this fact from ESlint by moving the second transaction to a separate function so that it doesn't appear nested any more:

```
.then(() => {
  return secondTransaction()
})


function secondTransaction() {
  return db.runTransaction(tran => {
    return tran.get(facturasRef).then(facturasDoc => {
      const holder = [];
      ...
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: I will try and I get back to you. Thanks for the quick answer again Doug!

Comment: It did work! Thanks you. Now code it's much cleaner and easy to read :D