# Firebase Cloud functions: warning

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am an android developer and I am trying to use cloud functions in firebase.I set up the entire thing without understanding much of the script apart from the basic structure.

**Most importantly I want to know how I can remove those warnings because I don't want it to stop working if something gets deprecated.**

The warnings from the interface:

```
  24:13  warning  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
  28:16  warning  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
  60:11  warning  Avoid nesting promises          promise/no-nesting
  60:11  warning  Avoid nesting promises          promise/no-nesting
  61:13  warning  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback
  65:16  warning  Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback

✖ 6 problems (0 errors, 6 warnings)
  0 errors and 4 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option
```

My code:

```
let functions = require('firebase-functions');

let admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref("Notifications").onWrite((change, context) => {
          const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
          console.log("after: ", afterData.topic);
          console.log("after: ", afterData.msg);    


            const payload = {
                data: {
                    data_type: "direct_message",
                    title: "New Message  " ,
                    message: afterData.msg,
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(afterData.topic, payload)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                            return;
                          })
                          .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                            return;
                          });
        });

exports.sendToOne = functions.database.ref("messages").onWrite((change, context) => {

     const afterData = change.after.val(); // data after the write
     const message = afterData.message;
     const receiverid = afterData.id;
          console.log("receiver id : ", receiverid);    
          console.log("receiver message : ", message);  


    return admin.database().ref("/users/"+receiverid).once('value').then(snap => {
        const senderName = snap.child("name").val();
        const token = snap.child("token").val();
        console.log("receiver name: ", senderName);
        console.log("receiver token: ", token);


            console.log("Construction the notification message.");
            const payload = {
                data: {
                    data_type: "direct_message",
                    title: "New Message",
                    message: message
                }
            };

            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                        .then(function(response) {
                            console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                            return;
                          })
                          .catch(function(error) {
                            console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                          return;
                          });
        });
    });
```

How do I remove these warnings, please help.

Comment: "_4 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option_"

Comment: I am not able to use  it, and it says potentially...and also I'd rather learn to fix the warnings myself

Comment: Consider doing searches for each warning message individually.  They have explanations.

Comment: I do not have much time so it would be very helpful if you could tell me how to fix the syntax

Comment: Just reading the warnings gives you good hints for what to do ... "_Unexpected function expression  prefer-arrow-callback_", well, don't use traditional anonymous function expressions, use arrow functions instead. "_Avoid nesting promises, promise/no-nesting_", don't nest promises.

Comment: I tried that Doug I did not understand much

Comment: @Teemu I understand but how do I do it

Comment: I saw https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844962/10800406
by Doug and it still is confusing

Comment: Yes.I just started yesterday so I am asking I have those arrows. Thank you for your help I will do it myself or bounty this later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two kinds of warnings, `prefer-arrow-callback` and `promise/no-nesting`

### [`prefer-arrow-callback`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback)

Like @Teemu pointed out in the comments, you just have to change your anonymous functions to arrow functions.

Based on the warning messages, the functions are in the lines 24, 28, 61 and 65, which are the majority of the `then` and `catch` in your code. You will have to refactor them to arrow functions. For example, instead of `.then(function(response) {` use `.then((response) => {`.

There are many reasons for this change, like improving readability, but I believe the most important is that this method doesn't bind the `this`.

You can read more about the [difference between traditional anonymous functions and arrow functions here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/).

### [`promise/no-nesting`](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/no-nesting.md)

In the [@DougStevenson answer you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49844962/10800406) you have the answer already. To explain it further, instead of having a promise (`.then()` or `.catch()` statement) inside another, is better to return the promise object in the first promise and call the second `then()` or `.catch()` afterwards.

In your code, the issue is that you have this nested promises:

```
return admin.database().ref("/users/"+receiverid).once('value').then(snap => { // Your first promise
    [...]
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload)
                        .then(function(response) { // Second promise
                            [...]
                         });
    });
```

To fix this, follow @Doug's advice and call the second promise after the first, something like this:

```
return admin.database().ref("/users/"+receiverid).once('value').then(snap => { // Your first promise
    [...]
    return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
    })
.then(function(response) { // Second promise
                            [...]
                         });
```

Comment: I was looking in the wrong places, and unable  to understand that simple thing...mostly because I am too exhausted. Thanks again for explaining

Comment: `.then(function(response) { // Second promise
                            [...]
                         });`

why is there no arrow here, and I am a bit confused where to catch the `error`

Comment: does this look ok?

 `return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token, payload);
    }).then((response)=> {
     console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
       return;
        })
        .catch((error)=> {
       console.log("Error sending message:", error);
        return;
        });`

Comment: Thanks a lot :D @GuillermoCacheda