# crash app when upload the image from gallery to firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

when the app is crashing , it says :

```
"java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method getToken(Z)Lcom/google/android/gms/tasks/Task; in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.minisign-uZwwNJVtsjlOVpgpqIRyHQ==/base.apk)at com.google.firebase.storage.internal.Util.getCurrentAuthToken(com.google.firebase:firebase-storage@@16.0.4:148)"
```

I have tried many things but didn't solve it .
My code :

```
final StorageReference fileReference=storageReference.child(imageuri.getLastPathSegment()+"."+getfileExtension(imageuri));
            uploadTask=fileReference.putFile(imageuri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    // Get a URL to the uploaded content
                    //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri();
                    //pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this,"Failed!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //pd.dismiss();
                }
            });
           }
```

and for my gradle :

```
{implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.4'

implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:1.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make sure you are using the latest versions of all the libraries, as shown in the [release notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844854/google-cloud-functions-warning-avoid-nesting-promises-promise-no-nesting).  You are also very behind on the version of [Firebase-UI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).  The latest is 6.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the [firebase sdk library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419) in the build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
```